# How to open default email client like Ms Outlook, Lotus, thunderbird from java program with attachemnt?

Tags: java, outlook, email-attachments, email-client

Though the question is asked so many times on the forum. I didn't find a solution to it atleast for Java. I googled it but in vain.

My requirement: I have to open the default email client(like MS Outlook, Lotus, Thunderbird) in the users machine which should auto attach the file to the email clinet.
My problem: I am not able to attach the file. I have tried various method listed down. But its not attaching the file. I am howvere little bit succedded to attach file in Lotus Notes 8.5. But didnt find solutions for outlook and other email clients.

My Approach(es):
1. Below code works fine with Lotus Notes 8.5 and it does auto aatch the file. But not working in other clients

```
Desktop fDesktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
String url = 
"mailTo:you@xyz.com,me@abc.com" (mailTo:you@xyz.com,me@abc.com%27) + 
"?subject=" + getEmailSubject() + 
 "&body=" + getEmailBody()+
 "&Attach=C:/temp/blah.txt";
 URI mailTo = new URI(url);
 fDesktop.mail(mailTo);
```

2.Our most of the users are outlooks users. So i want some solution which can work with Outlook (2007 and 2010)
For Outlook I tried with following. But in Vain. It does opening the client with To, Subject , Body but not attaching the file. Also I am getting "The Command line Argument is not valid. Please verify the Switch". I tried 
using swicthes also but not sure if I am doing it correct way.

```
      <a href='mailto:recip@domain.com?subject=Some subjectl&body=Bodytext.&attachment=""C:\temp\blah.txt""'>Click here 1</a>


       <a href='c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\outlook.exe' /c ipm.note /m   someone@gmail.com /a 'c:\temp\blah.txt'>Click here 2</a>

       <a  onclick="window.close();" href="mailto:?subject= Report&amp;body=Attach Report%0A as an email attachment%0A%0AFor 2008 April.&amp;&quot;&quot;C:\temp\blah.txt">Click here 3</A>

       <a  onclick="window.close();" href="mailto:?subject= Report&amp;body=Attach Report%0Aas%20an%20email%20attachment%0A%0AFor%202008%20April%2E&amp;&quot;&quot;C%3A%5Ctempt%5Cblah%2Etxt">Click here 4</a>
```

I need experts advice on this. I need it urgently for the project. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the OS level whichever email client is set as the default, that is the one that pops up. How to set it is clearly given in the link 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/unable-to-use-lotus-notes-as-default-e-mail/3be3a8e6-a2e6-42b6-99bb-cd2e29740507.

We did it this way.